# Boot from USB device

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media, liveusb

I'm trying to boot from a USB-Stick.

The legacy support of USB Mass Storage is enabled, but the devices are not listed in the bios under "*** USB Mass Storage Device Boot Setting ***"
[image]

On the other hand the sticks seem to be recognized because they appear in the boot menu under Removable Devices when Lagacy support is active. But when I select it in the boot menu, the following message appears:

> DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER

The PC can boot from a cd or from the internal hard drive, but not from an external usb device.

I have already tried out several sticks and a USB disk. But it is the same with all of them. On another PC I can boot from them without any problems.

I have created the sticks in many different ways.
I tried to extract the data manually to the stick and marked the partition with diskpart of windows as active.
I also tried to create the sticks with Rufus. But nothing worked.

Edit:
I used Windows 10 to create a Ubuntu 18.04.3 (64 bit) stick.
With Rufus I tried the following options:

- MBR / BIOS or UEFI
- GPT / UEFI (non CSM)

As filesystem I used "FAT32".
I also tried to enable the "Add fixes for old BIOSes" option.

Thanks for your help

Comment: that message looks more like windows hdd than pendrive

Comment: Which OS are you using to create the USB boot disk? What software are you trying to boot? When you use Rufus to create a USB drive, you can set the "Partition Scheme" to GPT or MBR, and  "Target System" to BIOS or UEFI. Which ones did you use, have you tried the other?

Comment: @JimDiroffII Thanks for your comment. I have added the information you requested to my post.

Comment: If the USB stick boots fine on another PC, then your system is the problem. Can you provide more details about your system?

Comment: @techitnik Certain OEMs placed a specific option in the BIOS to allow it to boot from a USB drive, and if the exact same USB drive boots on another PC, that's more that likely the issue _(this option is specific to **booting** from a USB)_

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to activate the boot from a USB drive with F8, it is necessary to activate this memory while it is inserted in the USB connector and entering BIOS configuration in the new menu that appears, mark HDD mode. "Generic USB Flash Disk 0.0 [HDD mode]"

[image]